# Is there any way to generate meaningful random Strings?

Tags: java, string, random

Is there any way to generate random Strings in java which are meaningful as well? I mean they should be valid English dictionary words.

Comment: You could randomize getting a word by itself...

Comment: Yes there are many ways. Go ahead.

Comment: So what have you tried? There are tons of answers out there...

Comment: do you mean anagrams?

Comment: Meaningful words are not random strings. You may choose a meaningful word randomly.

Comment: do you mean like this? http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/10/randomly-no-so-random.html

Comment: @ConcurrentHashMap Hey I just pinged a Java class ;)

Comment: @icza for choosing renadomly meaningful words I will have to keep those words with me, that's not what i want to do. and meaningful words can be random if we do not have any idea what the next word could be.

Comment: @peterLawrey, correct :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create a table/list of meaningful english word, then random an int to access the correspondante string.